# База данных в J2EE, GlassFish, ConnectionPool

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, glassfish, j2ee

Столкнулся с проблемой когда после создание якобы pool-а соединений, в одном методе берется 1 coonection, после conn.close() закрываю его, чтобы по идее его отдать pool-у обратно, но после закрытия, я не могу взять другой connection. Пишет соединение закрыто. В чем дело? Работаю через Netbeans 8.1, Пул настраиваю в админ консоли glassfish 4.0 по инструкции.
Мой код для вытягивания соединения:

```
private static Connection conn;
private static InitialContext ic;
private static DataSource pool;

public static Connection getConnection() throws NamingException, SQLException {
    ic = new InitialContext();
    pool = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/library");
    if (conn == null) {
        conn = pool.getConnection();
    }
    return conn;
}
```

После этого фрагмента перестает работать пул:

```
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = Database.getConnection();

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from genre order by name");
        while (rs.next()) {
            Genre genre = new Genre();
            genre.setID(rs.getLong("id"));
            genre.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            genreList.add(genre);
        }

    } catch (SQLException | NamingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GenreList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GenreList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда вы вызываете pool.getConnection(), вы не получаете в чистом виде подключение, обычно оно обёрнуто каким-нибудь враппером (зависит от сервера приложений).

Враппер как-раз нужен чтобы отследить закрытие, т.е. когда вы вызываете conn.close(), враппер возвращает подключение в пул и выставляет у себя флаг, что подключение закрыто, т.к. теоретически враппер могут дёрнуть дальше по коду.

Вам не нужно сохранять подключение, которое вы получили из пула, т.е. надо написать так:

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws NamingException, SQLException {
    if (pool == null) {
        ic = new InitialContext();
        pool = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/library");
    }
    return pool.getConnection();
}
```

Comment: Ёмоё, точняк, вот смотрю на код и не могу догнать что я сохранил только одно соединение, огромное спасибо))

Answer (score 0):

DataSource действительно с реализацией PooledConnection? У вас должен быть специальный DataSource и если вы используете JNDI то должна быть операция bind для подключения PooledConnectionDataSource.